# Data is nil even after assigning when doing navigation in ios, objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to pass a text value, image and uitextview from one view controller to another. But these take values of nil even after doing the assignment.

The titellabel, imageView and descriptionView are null after the assignment statement is executed. I have allocated and initialised the DetailsViewController but still these show up nil after assigning value. Can you tell as to what I am missing here. Why they are not taking the values assigned.

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    //DetailsViewController *view = [[DetailsViewController alloc]init];
    DetailsViewController *view = [[DetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSLog([[self.xmlNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"]);
    view.titleLabel.text = [[self.xmlNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
    view.imageView.image = [self.images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    view.descriptionView.text = [[self.xmlNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"description"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:TRUE];
}
```

Comment: Step one: Format your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NAVEEN RAM,

You cant set the properties of the viewComponment before they are loaded.

```
view.titleLabel.text = [[self.xmlNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
view.imageView.image = [self.images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
view.descriptionView.text = [[self.xmlNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"description"];
```

The above three statements will set the textLabel,textView and UIImageView's property which is not yet loaded so it will never show up.

What you can do :

Declare three properties one for holding string second one for holding image and third one for holding descriptionText in `DetailsViewController.h`

Let's call them as

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIImage *passedImage;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *descriptionText;
```

Modify didselect row at index path as

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    //DetailsViewController *view = [[DetailsViewController alloc]init];
    DetailsViewController *view = [[DetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSLog([[self.xmlNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"]);
    view.title = [[self.xmlNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
    view.passedImage = [self.images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    view.descriptionText = [[self.xmlNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"description"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:TRUE];
}
```

and finally in ViewDidLoad of DetailsViewController set the image and label as

```
self.titleLabel.text = self.title;
self.imageView.image = self.passedImage;
self.descriptionView.text = self.descriptionText;
```

Hope it helps